# clang-format keeps moving control blocks to single line

Tags: clang-format

I cannot figure out how this started.  I don't even think I changed anything.  Maybe I updated it?  Using `clang-format version 15.0.7` in vim writing C. Invoking via:

```
map <C-K> :py3f /usr/share/clang/clang-format.py<cr>
```

... But does the same thing from the standalone program.

```c
if (x >= y)
{ 
    return 0;
}
```

keeps changing to

```c
if (x >= y)
{ return 0; }
```

All relevant options (as far as I know):

```
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never    
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false                                                                 
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline    
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never                                                               
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: None    
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false     
...
BraceWrapping:                                                                                           
  AfterCaseLabel: false                                                                                  
  AfterClass: false     
  AfterControlStatement: Always                                                                          
  AfterEnum: false     
  AfterExternBlock: false                                                                                
  AfterFunction: false                                                                                   
  AfterNamespace: false                                                                                  
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false     
  AfterStruct: false                                                                                     
  AfterUnion: false                                                                                      
  BeforeCatch: false                                                                                     
  BeforeElse: true     
  IndentBraces: false                                                                                    
  SplitEmptyFunction: true                                                                               
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true     
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
```

Answer (score 0):

wtf... The mystery config was setting:

```
AfterFunction: True
```

That is completely unrelated and must certainly be a bug.  Leaving here for anyone else who has this issue.